# Проверять в словаре существование элемента python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

У меня есть список `{"result":"ok","code":0,"data":{"nickName":"habast","uid":3731878,"accountRank":4}}`, но в нем может не быть некоторых данных `{"result":"ok","code":0,"data":{"nickName":"habast"}}`. Как проверять элемент на существование и если не существует то добавлять его и заменять на `'None'`. Пример `{"result":"ok","code":0,"data":{"nickName":"habast"}}` преобразовываем в `{"result":"ok","code":0,"data":{"nickName":"habast","uid":3731878,"accountRank":4,"uid":"None","accountRank":"None"}}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335445/recursively-replace-dictionary-values-with-matching-key

Comment: @splash58 там такие ответы страшные, какбудто никто питон не учил) тот вопрос через dict.update решается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict` в питоне имеет метод

```
 |  setdefault(self, key, default=None, /)
 |      Insert key with a value of default if key is not in the dictionary.
 |      
 |      Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.
```

Установить значение по умолчанию, если ключа нет в словаре. Тоесть

```
rs['data'].setdefault('uid', None)
```

исправит ваш словарь.

Также при обработке входных данных полезно забирать значения из словаря через

```
uid = rs['data'].get('uid', None)
```

Вернет значение `None` вместо `KeyError`.

Ещё можно сделать прототип по схеме данных:

```
schema = {"uid": None, "rank":0}
rs['data'] = dict(schema).update(rs['data'])
```

Тут dict() создаст копию схемы, а update() обновит поля на нужные значения.

Comment: мне кажется, что нужно делать что-то типа array_replace_recursive из php. Данные, вероятно могут отсутствовать произвольные

Comment: @splash58 пока вы писали коммент я какраз дополнил ответ этим вариантом

Answer (score 0):

Используйте операторы `in` и `not in` для проверки наличия или отсутствия ключей в словаре, например:

```
rs = {"result":"ok","code":0,"data":{"nickName":"habast"}}
if 'uid' not in rs['data']:
    rs['data']['uid'] = 'None'

if 'accountRank' not in rs['data']:
    rs['data']['accountRank'] = 'None'

print(rs)
# {'result': 'ok', 'code': 0, 'data': {'nickName': 'habast', 'uid': 'None', 'accountRank': 'None'}}
```

Comment: а json сразу str в вид {"result":"ok","code":0,"data":{"nickName":"habast"}} переводит?

Comment: а причем тут json?

Comment: @ТерновойЕгор, при парсинге json вы получите словарь питона, который и будет выглядеть как в `rs`